# Set Cassandra 3.10 cluster

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra, I am setting up a cluster on Cassandra 3.10 (2 nodes) but from log looks like the seed cannot talk to each other. I am able to ping server from other host. 
Getting following error in the log
DEBUG [MessagingService-Outgoing-/ip_adress-Gossip] 2017-03-30 14:23:19,880 OutboundTcpConnection.java:495 - Unable to connect to /ip_address
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

I do not know, why there is / before the ip_address
I have substituted the real ip_address with word ip_address

Comment: If you are using a host name instead of IP address, then add the host name in host entries

Answer (score 0):

[No route to host] apparently, it looks like nodes cannot communicate with each other. make sure you can ssh/ping from both servers to each other. Certainly, you'll need to address network issues first before taking next steps.

Comment: I do have but looks like they need to communicate on port 9042

Comment: tcp transport /client connection would need port#9042.. nodes talk with each other via gossip protocol on port 7000 or 7001(secured) i.e. depends what port you chose to use